# react-redux prevent rerendering of list items when the state changes

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a list item callled Row. The Row has three sections, I have stored the width of each sections in a state

```
 rowWidth: [
     {
       id: 'name',       
       width: 200,
        
     },
     {
       id: 'size',       
       width: 70,
       
     },
     {
       id: 'status',      
       width: 150,
       
     },
     {
       id: 'progress',       
       width: 200,
       
     },
     {
       id: 'lasttry',       
       width: 200,
      
     },
     {
       id: 'eta',     
       width: 50,
       
     },
   ]
```

I change width of a single column by an external handle which updates the store.

```
switch (actions.type) {
     case consts.CHANGE_HEADER_WIDTH :  return {
       ...state,
       headerWidth: state.headerWidth.map((item) =>
         item.id === actions.payload.id ?  { ...item, width: actions.payload.neWidth }  : item
       ),
     } 
       
     break;
default : return state;
}
```

This is the row

```
  const headerWidth = useSelector((state) => state.ui.headerWidth)
  
  
  const getWidth = useCallback((id) => {
    const l = _.find(headerWidth, function (item) {
      return item.id === id
    })
    return l.width
  })

    return(
         <Row>
    <Section1 style={{ width: getRow('name') }}/>
    <Section2 style={{ width: getRow('size') }}/>
    <Section3 style={{ width: getRow('status') }}/>
    </Row>
    )
```

My question is - how do I change the width of these divs without rerendering row

Comment: If the width changes and you don't do a new render you will never see the components with the updated width value. If this is what you want then you have to use another approach. Don't store the in the redux state.

Comment: Updating state rerenders the UI, if you don't rerender the UI you can't see what the state was updated to.

Comment: If you don't want to render Section component(s) that didn't change then you can use [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) to make these components pure components.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help. I understand that there has to be a rerender in order to view the state change.